# Multi-threaded connection manager with Jersey Apache Client 4

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-client

I have a Jersey client up and running, using the Apache Client 4 library, like this:

```
private Client createClient() {
    ApacheHttpClient4Config cc = new DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config();
    // boring stuff here
    return ApacheHttpClient4.create(cc);
}
```

But this by default uses a `BasicClientConnManager`, which doesn't allow multi-threaded connections.

The `ApacheHttpClient4Config` Javadoc says that I need to set the `PROPERTY_CONNECTION_MANAGER` to a `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` instance if I want multi-threaded operation. I can do this, and it works OK:

```
private Client createClient() {
    ApacheHttpClient4Config cc = new DefaultApacheHttpClient4Config();
    cc.getProperties().put(ApacheHttpClient4Config.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_MANAGER,
        new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());
    // boring stuff here
    return ApacheHttpClient4.create(cc);
}
```

But `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` is deprecated. This is annoying.

The more modern version is `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`. Unfortunately, though, the `ApacheHttpClient4.create()` method requires the connection manager to be an implementation of `ClientConnectionManager` (itself deprecated), and `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` doesn't implement that interface. So if I try to use it, my connection manager gets ignored and we're back to a `BasicClientConnManager`.

How can I end up with a thread-safe client without using anything that's deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the client as follows (see https://github.com/phillbarber/connection-leak-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/phillbarber/connectionleak/IntegrationTestThatExaminesConnectionPoolBeforeAndAfterRun.java#L30-L33):

```
    client = new ApacheHttpClient4(new ApacheHttpClient4Handler(HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .build(), null, false));
```